# How to get JavaScript popup window to not open when url equals false?

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup

I'm trying to have my javaScript popup not popup when the url has ("page.html?popup=false").

my popup code:

```
<script>
                    $(window).load( function(){
                        if (location.search.indexOf('popup=false') < 0){
                            rplm({
                                    title: "Better Health and Wellness",
                                    text: '<h1 style="float: inherit; font-weight: 100;">Subscribe and receive daily healthy recipes that target your specific conditions and needs.</h1></br><ul style="text-align: left; font-weight: 600; margin-bottom: 12px;"><li><svg class="checkmark" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="20px" height="20px" viewBox="0 0 512 512" enable-background="new 0 0 512 512" xml:space="preserve"><polygon id="check-mark-icon" points="398.218,92.985 199.729,291.475 113.754,205.476 50,269.242 199.733,419.015 462,156.726 "></polygon></svg>Food based approaches for improved health.</li><li><svg class="checkmark" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="20px" height="20px" viewBox="0 0 512 512" enable-background="new 0 0 512 512" xml:space="preserve"><polygon id="check-mark-icon" points="398.218,92.985 199.729,291.475 113.754,205.476 50,269.242 199.733,419.015 462,156.726 "></polygon></svg>Research based solutions that are easy to follow</li><li><svg class="checkmark" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="20px" height="20px" viewBox="0 0 512 512" enable-background="new 0 0 512 512" xml:space="preserve"><polygon id="check-mark-icon" points="398.218,92.985 199.729,291.475 113.754,205.476 50,269.242 199.733,419.015 462,156.726 "></polygon></svg>Instant access to 3 amazing superfood smoothie guides</li><li><svg class="checkmark" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="20px" height="20px" viewBox="0 0 512 512" enable-background="new 0 0 512 512" xml:space="preserve"><polygon id="check-mark-icon" points="398.218,92.985 199.729,291.475 113.754,205.476 50,269.242 199.733,419.015 462,156.726 "></polygon></svg>Experts to bring you their incredible knowledge and recipes </li><li><svg class="checkmark" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="20px" height="20px" viewBox="0 0 512 512" enable-background="new 0 0 512 512" xml:space="preserve"><polygon id="check-mark-icon" points="398.218,92.985 199.729,291.475 113.754,205.476 50,269.242 199.733,419.015 462,156.726 "></polygon></svg>Workout plans for all ages</li></ul><form id="myForm" action="submit.php" method="post"><div class="customFieldset"><span><fieldset><input type="text" placeholder="Enter Your Email" name="email"><div class="rm-input-error"></div></fieldset></span></div><div class="rm-confirm-button-container"><button class="confirm" style="display: inline-block; box-shadow: rgba(247, 223, 8, 0.8) 0px 0px 2px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0470588) 0px 0px 0px 1px inset; background-color: rgb(247, 223, 8);" id="reg-submit" type="submit">Subscribe</button><div class="la-ball-fall"></div></div></form>',
                                    type: "",
                                    imageUrl: "images/letter.png",
                                    animation: 'jello',
                                    modalNOverlay: 'black',
                                    overlay: 'blur',
                                    allowOutsideClick: true ,
                                    html: true,
                                    showLoaderOnConfirm: true,
                                    resize
                            });
                       };
                    });
            </script>
```

Comment: Just check the query string: `if (location.search.indexOf('popup=false') >= 0) { rplm(...); }`

Comment: I edited my code but the popup still comes up with the url ?popup=false?

Comment: Can you please create some fiddle ?

Comment: Your if statement should read `indexOf('popup=false') > -1` as you don't want it to match... otherwise the popup will run when `popup=false` string is found. - Sorry @squeamishossifrage I felt OP wasn't getting it.

Comment: @evolutionxbox I change my statement to > -1 and I reload the page and it still came up. Maybe it could be another thing?

Comment: Sorry. I made a mistake. You want `rplm` to run, except when `popup=false` is in the query string. Then your if statement should be `if (location.search.indexOf('popup=false') < 0) {`.

Comment: @evolutionxbox That's okay. I made the correction to the code, but it seems to still use the popup?

Comment: Really? Take out the popup code and replace it with a console log. Go from there.